# Blazor WASM + AAD B2C + Custom Authorisation

Tags: c#, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-client-side, claims

I have a Blazor client (WASM) app that integrates with AAD B2C for authentication.

After authentication, I want to call my own API for further authorisation information. The reason I want to do this rather than getting B2C to call my API is I will have series of different apps using the same B2C, with different claims, roles and other information etc.

I've tried every tutorial I can find, but nothing seems to wire up.

My Program.cs has this:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    var settings = config.AzureAdB2C;

    var authentication = options.ProviderOptions.Authentication;
    authentication.Authority = $"{settings.Instance}{settings.Domain}/{settings.SignInPolicy}";
    authentication.ClientId = settings.ClientApplicationId;
    authentication.ValidateAuthority = false;
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add($"{settings.ServerAppId}/{settings.DefaultScope}");
    //options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
});

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

And for example, I've tried this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, UserInfoClaims>();

public class UserInfoClaims : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private static IEnumerable<SimpleClaim> roles;
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ...
```

But it doesn't get hit.

**Is it possible to rewrite claims in WASM after B2C authentication?**

And if not, is there an event I can wire up to after successful authentication to just manage my own role-like alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by implementing your own AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory

```
    public class ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> 
    where TAccount : RemoteUserAccount
{
    public ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
    : base(accessor)
    { 
      //Any dependency injection or construction of objects 
      //inside this constructor usually leads to wasm memory exceptions
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(TAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (account != null)
        {     
            //Add logic here to get custom user information
            //Add Claims to the user identity like so
            var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("type", "value"));
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Then on start up when adding authentication you do the following

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication()
    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ExampleClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>();
```

Comment: Does this work with refresh tokens and all that?  I think it must.  I tested it with KMSI and AD-B2C and when I selected Log in again, it round tripped to the server and hit this code again.  I would presume it would have to do the same for a refresh token event.  And this is just for WASM and not server.

Comment: That sound more like you still had a valid token in a cookie available that could allow you to log in. I think there is some extra configuration required in the wasm client to enable actual token refresh worth have a look in the options in the call the setup the auth service in the client startup.