# Blazor WASM Azure AD - Adding Custom Claims

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, addition, blazor-webassembly, claims

I have a **Blazer WASM** app authenticating via **Azure AD**, and I need to fetch additional claims from a separate API.

I want to bring in these claims after Azure-AD authentication into the principle object so that I can perform simplified page [Authorization(role=.., policy=...)] checks.

In ASP.NET, one way of modifying claims is to register a custom IClaimsTransformation class which can be used to insert additional claims into the claims principle.
Unfortunately, **Blazor WASM** with **Azure AD** authentication does not appear to support the use of IClaimsTransformation.

Do you know of a way to add additional claims into the existing claims principle?

*NOTE: Another option I ruled out is using the new Azure Custom Claims provider, but it's in a preview state and I strongly wish to avoid going that route.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor WASM + AAD B2C + Custom Authorisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135694/blazor-wasm-aad-b2c-custom-authorisation)

Comment: In part, but I ran into problems as there was 1 missing piece which Dylan (below) included which the answer you shared did not include. The missing piece was to set options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role"; which then enabled me to use the [Authorization(Role="myrole1")] attribute on my page. Being able to use Authorization attributes against the roles I added is a core requirement for me.

Comment: Here's an answer that demonstrates how to add roles to an existing user.  You can use the same technique, but get them from the API, and add a new `ClaimsIdentity` to your `ClaimsPrincipal` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75771418/13065781

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks. That was one of the first solutions I tried. For me it did not work whatever I tried. Further research done I came to the conclusion that it requires calling services.AddAuthentication() which is not available in Blazor WASM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory` method in order to add claims, in the Azure AD authenth process.

```
public class CustomUserFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserAccount>
{
    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor)
    {

    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(CustomUserAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (initialUser?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
        {
            var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)initialUser.Identity;

            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("claim_type", "claim_value"));
        }

        return initialUser ?? new ClaimsPrincipal();
    }
}

public class CustomUserAccount : RemoteUserAccount
{
    [JsonPropertyName("groups")]
    public string[] Groups { get; set; } = default!;

    [JsonPropertyName("roles")]
    public string[] Roles { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

And you will need to call `AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory`:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services,IConfiguration config)
{

    services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
    {
        config.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
        options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(config["AzureAd:Scope"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("AzureAd:Scope"));
        options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
    }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomUserFactory>();


    return services;
}
```

Comment: I was working on a similar code piece as you provided, but my Authorization attributes were not working for the roles I specified. One missing piece which you included was to add options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role"; After which [Authorization(Role="xyz")] then started working.